# Dynamically add fixed-height panels to a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
JScrollPane contentpane = new JScrollPane(panel);
JButton add  = new JButton("ADD");
add.actionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(){
          MyPanel newpanel = new MyPanel("title","Button"); //MyPanel is a class which extends JPanel and contains constructor MyPanel(String TitleToSet ,String ButtonTitleTOAdd)
           panel.add(newpanel);
           panel.repaint(); 
     }) ;
```

I have used this code thinking that it will add the MyPanel to the grid layout dynamically and "panel" would be scrollable if more "MyPanel"s are added. However, this was not the case, 1st "MyPanel" filled whole "panel" and on adding second "MyPanel" (by clicking button "Add"), the 1st "MyPanel" was shrinked to make space for second one to be added.. and on adding more, all the "MyPanel"s were fit in the viewport instead of making the "panel" scrollable.. How to add those "MyPanel"s dynamically and making the "panel" scrollable on adding more of those?? Any  help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html :

> By default JScrollPane uses ScrollPaneLayout to handle the layout of
> its child Components. ScrollPaneLayout determines the size to make the
> viewport view in one of two ways:
>
> 1. [...]
> 2. getPreferredSize is used.

You should add the line

```
panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, panel.getComponents().size() * SUB_PANEL_HEIGHT));
```

to your ActionListener.

Full example:

```
package main;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.Timer;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        panel.add(new JLabel("BOO"));
        panel.add(new JButton("BBBB"));
        
        JScrollPane contentpane = new JScrollPane(panel);
        frame.add(contentpane);
        
        new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JPanel newpanel = new JPanel();
                newpanel.add(new JLabel("LOL"));
                panel.add(newpanel);
                System.out.println(100 * panel.getComponents().length);
                panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 100 * panel.getComponents().length));
                contentpane.validate();
            }
        }).start();
        
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , It worked perfectly,, I even tried using absolute layout. However I didn't understand the part when you set preferred size , Why did you set the width of the panel 0 ?? [panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 100 * panel.getComponents().length));]

Comment: JScrollPane sets the view width to max(view.getPreferredSize().getWidth(), scrollPane.getWidth()). By setting the view's preferred width to 0, I ensure that scrolling occurs only vertically.